# Cannot Access Second Website After Setting Up VHost Configuration on CentOS 7 and Cloudflare

Tags: apache, cloudflare, vhosts

I'm currently trying to set up a vhost configuration for my second domain on CentOS 7 with Cloudflare.

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built: May 30 2023 14:01:11
```

I executed the following commands for the directory path:

```
chown apache:apache /var/www/html/secondweb -R
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/secondweb
```

And here is the content of the vhost configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@secondwebsite
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/secondweb"
    ServerName secondwebsite.net
    ErrorLog /var/www/html/log
    CustomLog /var/www/html/log-requests.txt combined

    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
        <If "-f %{REQUEST_FILENAME}">
            SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9080"
        </If>
    </FilesMatch>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
    AddHandler php80-fcgi .php
    Action php80-fcgi /cgi-bin/php80.fcgi

    <Directory "/var/www/html/secondweb">
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +Includes +ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <IfModule dir_module>
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.htm index.html
    </IfModule>

    SSLEngine on
    #SSLProtocol -All +TLSv1.3
    SSLCipherSuite EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH
    SSLCertificateFile /var/www/html/cer.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/www/html/cer.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /var/www/html/origin.pem
    #Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
    #Header always set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self';"
    ServerSignature Off
    #ServerTokens Prod
</VirtualHost>
```

However, the problem is that after restarting httpd, the site cannot be accessed and I'm getting the following error using the Opera browser:

```
This site can't be reached
secondwebsite.net refused to connect.

Try:

    Checking the connection
    Checking the proxy and the firewall
    ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Can anyone help me identify which part might be causing the issue?

second website running normally